# Why do strings produce a different output for post increment (something++) vs. adding 1 (something = something +1)?

Tags: javascript, post-increment, coercion

We know about post-increment and pre-increment in programming languages. As far as I know, post-increment means to increment the value for the next statement. So, `something++` is the equivalent to `something = something + 1`, isn’t it?

But why do `something = something + 1` and `something++` produce a different output when `something` is a string?

```js
let something = "5";
let anything = 5;

something = something + 1;
console.log(something); // "51"

anything = anything + 1;
console.log(anything); // 6
```

```js
let something = "5";
let anything = 5;

something++;
console.log(something); // 6

anything++;
console.log(anything); // 6
```

I know about automatic type-casting, but why is `something + 1` coerced into a string, but `something++` into a number?

Comment: Because that’s how the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) describes it: `++` coerces its operand into a number, `+` into a string in this scenario.

Comment: @SebastianSimon can you please mention the reference/documentation ?

Comment: @ggorlen js isn't a strongly typed language. So when you add `string + number`, it will automatic convert into string/number i guess (type casting). My question is - why ++ convert into `string`, where `something+1` convert into number.

Comment: @Robin _“My question is why `++` convert into string, where `something+1` convert into number.”_ — you confused the two. `++` coerces its operand to a number; `+` coerces both to a string (eventually; in this scenario).

Comment: @ggorlen is `something++` equivalent to `something = something +1` ? If yes, why it produces different output ? That's my question. I hope you understand my point of view. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen No, `something` is coerced to a number at `something++`.

Comment: @ggorlen It’s in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see my confusion. I was looking at the code block. The way the question is laid out doesn't make much sense to me. Sorry about that. Even so, the reason the behavior is as it is comes down to "the spec says so".

Comment: Found the answer in ECMAScript spec, Thanks @SebastianSimon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [specification for the `++` operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation), you’ll see that step 2 forces its operand to be a number, whereas `+` doesn’t.

> ### 12.4.4 Postfix Increment Operator
>
> #### 12.4.4.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> *[UpdateExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-UpdateExpression)* : *[LeftHandSideExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression)* `++`
>
> 1. Let *lhs* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
> 2. **Let *oldValue* be ? [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-tonumber)(? [GetValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-getvalue)(*lhs*)).**
> 3. Let *newValue* be the result of adding the value `1` to *oldValue*, using the same rules as for the `+` operator (see [12.8.5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers)).
> 4. Perform ? [PutValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-putvalue)(*lhs*, *newValue*).
> 5. Return *oldValue*.

Answer (score 2):

These are two different operators

`++` is post increment it implicitly tries to coerce operands to number and then performs increment [`++ Ref`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

```js
let increment = (val) =>{
  return val++
}

console.log(increment('5'))
console.log(increment(''))
console.log(increment([]))
console.log(increment({}))
console.log(increment(undefined))
```

whereas the other one is addition when used for numeric value but works as concatenation for string  [`+ Ref`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

```js
let increment = (val) => {
  return val + 1
}

console.log(increment('5'))
console.log(increment(''))
console.log(increment([]))
console.log(increment({}))
console.log(increment(undefined))
```